# Local declaration of "speed view" hides instance variable

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

So I have been searching in a few hours for why my iPhone app hates me. This is the error I get:
Warning: local declaration of 'speedView' hides instance variable.
Here is my .m file

```
@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize speedCount;
@synthesize speedView;
@synthesize popoverController;

- (void)setspeedView:(UILabel *)speedView
{
    [speedView setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",speedCount]];
    speedCount = 0;
    speedCount++;
}
```

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <LoginDelegate,WEPopoverParentView,PopoverControllerDelegate,MainMenuDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,UIAccelerometerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    IBOutlet MKMapView *userMap;
    IBOutlet UILabel *speedView;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *speedView;
@property(nonatomic) int speedCount;
```

I really don't understand why it says that I am hiding the instance variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a ivar (an instance variable) called `speedView`.

In your method

```
- (void)setspeedView:(UILabel *)speedView
```

`speedView` is a local variable whose name clashes with the ivar.

If you are using a modern version of the compiler just remove the `@synthesize` directive.

It will be automatically added by the compiler in this form

```
@synthesize speedView = _speedView
```

which will create the ivar `_speedView`, whose name doesn't clash anymore with the local variable.

Also note that declaring both the instance variable and the property is redundant. The ivar will be automatically created by the (implicit) `@synthesize` directive.

Here's a "modern" version of your class:

### .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <LoginDelegate,WEPopoverParentView,PopoverControllerDelegate,MainMenuDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,UIAccelerometerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *speedView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *userMap;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
@property (nonatomic) int speedCount;
```

### .m

```
@implementation MainViewController

- (void)setspeedView:(UILabel *)speedView {
    [speedView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.speedCount]];
    self.speedCount = 0;
    self.speedCount++;
}
```

Please note:

- properties are nice: use them whenever you can
- `@synthesize` is implicit
- the implicit version of `@sythesize` declares a `_ivar` for the property `ivar`
- always access variables through the getters/setters, i.e. `self.ivar`, a part from `init` methods. If you need to access the var directly use `_ivar` or `self->_ivar`

As a final remark, this looks a bit weird

```
self.speedCount = 0;
self.speedCount++;
```

and it could be replaced with

```
self.speedCount = 1;
```

Are you sure it's what you mean? Also, as noted in the comments by others, you are not using the method parameter `speedView`. That smells bad and you may want to double check your implementation.

Comment: +1 This may be a good opportunity to teach OP how to access an ivar in spite of it being shadowed by a local variable :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yep, I just added a note about removing `@synthesize`

Comment: +1. After removing @sythesize, there is also an explicitly declared ivar to remove still. And, the method doesn't seem like it needs the parameter to begin with.

Comment: Well, I meant the `self->speedView` dirty trick, but changing the synthesized name also works fine.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight oh sorry I didn't get that. Well it's kinda dirty an I prefer not to mention that too much :P

Comment: i really appreciate the help

Comment: @GabrielePetronella, one last issue is the unused parameter

Comment: How should i change that? speedView is my UIlabel that i want to update

Comment: any suggestions on the correct way of setting speedView? Thank you for all your help

Comment: @mrios it depends on what you want to do. If you want change the text from "outside" the class just make a method `-(void)setSpeedText` which updates the label text.

Comment: I would like to update my uilabel with a user current speed while on a bike or car etc? What steps would I have to take?

Comment: One way or another you have to update the `text` property of `speedLabel`. Just decide from where. You can either expose the label directly or provide a convenience method that receives the text as parameter and sets the label text.

Comment: Would I be able to do that under the - (void)setspeedView:(UILabel *)speedView method? Or Should i delete this?

Comment: That seems unnecessary. You don't want a setter of the label, you just want to modify its text.

Comment: I frankly don't know how to be clearer. You want to do `self.speedLabel.text = @"Whatever`. Just decide where you want do perform such operation.